# what will be a good artistic world or phrase for close cooperation for mutual success

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

what will be a good artistic word or phrase for close cooperation for mutual success.The cooperation of two parties (one with stronger power, second with weaker power, but huge dedication) where each strives to contribute their input for joint success and well-being.

Comment: What's wrong with *cooperation*? You've tagged this "idiom"; is that right? (Did you read the tag excerpt and the tag wiki?). What sort of thing are you actually looking for? Could you edit in an example sentence of how such a word is to be used?

Comment: I would go with "rare".

Answer (score 5):

Symbiosis - A relationship between people, companies etc. that is to the advantage of both. Eg. She imagined us living in a perfect father and son symbiosis.

Answer (score 3):

In an artistic context, the word I hear most often is simply **collaboration**.

Mirriam-Webster:

> to work with another person or group in order to achieve or do something

Answer (score 3):

[Synergy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy#Human_synergy)

(Although non-native speakers should be aware that this is a buzzword used primarily between businesspeople, and is a better word to use in a presentation or speech than in actual everyday conversation.)